# Trying to write a character to a file using fstream: no match for 'operator<<'

Tags: c++, arrays, operators, fstream, ofstream

So, I am trying to create a program that reads a character from a file, stores it all into a character array and then writes a new file, except that the raw number of every character is increased by one(most experienced programmers here will know what I am talking about). So I am basically trying to make my own encryption algorithm. However I get a very weird error:
`<various paths here>\main.cpp|27|error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ifstream {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>}' and 'char')|`
I've heard about this error alot around but all I see is that it only happens when people use class-defined functions, thing that I did not do in my program.
This error also came with a note that I think people might find it useful to help me out:
`<various paths here>\main.cpp|27|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::ifstream {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>}' to 'int'|`
The source code is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int array_size = 1024000;
    char Str[array_size];
    int position = 0;
    long double fsize = position;

    ifstream finput("in.txt");
    ifstream foutput("out.txt");
    if(finput.is_open()) {
        cout << "File Opened successfully. Storing file data into array." << endl;
        while(!finput.eof() && position < array_size) {
            finput.get(Str[position]);
            position++;
            fsize = position;
            cout << "Processed data: " << fsize / 1000 << "KB" << endl;
        }
        Str[position-1] = '\0';

        cout << "Storing done, encoding..." << endl << endl;
        for(int i = 0; Str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            cout << Str[i] << "changed to " << char(Str[i] + 1) << endl;
            foutput << Str[i] += 1;
        }

    } else {
        cout << "File could not be opened. File must be named in.txt and must not be in use by another program." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note: I have been using fstream to output strings(not characters, keep this in mind) on a file other times, and it worked just fine!

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `ifstream foutput` instead of `ofstream foutput` (you have to declare it output stream instead of input stream.

1. Replace `ifstream foutput("out.txt");` with `ofstream foutput("out.txt");`
2. Moreover, change `foutput << Str[i] += 1` to `foutput << (Str[i] += 1)` to remove error because of operator precedence.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ifstream foutput("out.txt");
> ```

That's an *input* stream, not an output stream. Change it to `std::ofstream` to get an output stream.

---

You will then get another error here:

> ```
> foutput << Str[i] += 1;
> ```

That's because of operator precedence. Fix it by inserting parentheses:

```
foutput << (Str[i] += 1);
```